# Angular runtime error after nx migrate to v15

Tags: angular, ngrx, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm in the process of migrating our monorepo Angular app from v12 to v16 via `nx migrate`, migrating one version at a time. Everything has gone smoothly through v14. The v15 migration itself went well but we are now encountering a new runtime error in our app (both dev and prod builds succeed).

One of the Angular libs in our monorepo is leveraging NgRx. Upon activating a route that lives in that lib / module, we're receiving the following runtime error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PlatformEffects' before initialization
```

Below is the module definition in question:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromReducer.platformFeatureKey, fromReducer.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([PlatformEffects]),
  ],
})
export class PlatformModule {}
```

`PlatformEffects` is an injectable class containing NgRx effects.

The source code hasn't changed between versions 14 and 15, so I'm at a loss as to where the problem is. Any ideas?